# Facebook authorization access token?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using the tutorial code...

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.android.*;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.*;

public class FacebookSSO extends Activity {

Facebook facebook = new Facebook("ID");

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    facebook.authorize(this,new String[] { "offline_access", "publish_stream", "email" },

        new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {}
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

I'm wondering... once the user has authenticated how would I store the access token? couldn't see any mention of it on the tutorial.

Comment: What I've been doing is not to store it at all. Only retrieving it using Facebook.getAccessToken when needed - meaning new one is created every time application is recreated (I have Facebook instance stored in FBApplication to share it among multiple Activities). But am curious to hear advantages for storing it.

Answer (score 5):

```
facebook.authorize(this,new String[] { "offline_access", "publish_stream", "email" },

    new DialogListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}
    String token=facebook.getAccessToken();  //get access token
    save(token);
    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

    @Override
    public void onError(DialogError e) {}

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {}
});
}

private void save(String token){
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
prefs.edit().putString("Token", token).commit();
}
```

i.e save it in sharedpreferences

Answer (score 0):

FYI. facebook.authorize had deprecated since Facebook SDK 3

Answer (score -1):

Try in this way

```
@Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                            // Function to handle complete event
                            // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                            editor.putString("access_token",
                                    facebook.getAccessToken());
                            editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                    facebook.getAccessExpires());
                            editor.commit();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(DialogError error) {
                            // Function to handle error

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                            // Function to handle Facebook errors

                        }
```